# wdired mode: create, copy, delete files and directories

Tags: emacs, dired, writable

I know I can move files by renaming them in wdired mode. I am wondering if there is a chance of creating, copying, deleting files/directories in writable dired mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `C-h m` in Wdired mode tells you this, among other things:

> In WDired mode, you can edit the names of the files in the
>   buffer, the target of the links, and the permission bits of the
>   files.

and this:

> The only editable texts in a WDired buffer are filenames,
>   symbolic link targets, and filenames permission.

Just use `C-x C-q` to toggle back to regular Dired mode, where you can easily create, copy, and delete files and directories.

Comment: I see. Though wdired is magnificent, it could be even better, because actually if you need create or duplicate (copy) a lot of files creating them through one-by-one minibuffer input is tedious, I will probably use command line for that.